# Laravel :error when updating the database after editing data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have two tables table "technician" and table "user" with a connection one to one and I have a form through which I edit the technician information. When I save the changes I get an error and the update doesn't work.Here is my form my code and a screenshot of the error Thank you in advance.

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::patch('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')-
>name('technicien.update');
```

**edit.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $moyenne_avis->id , $actif->id , $user->nom , $user->prenom ,$user->email ) }}" method="update">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nom">Nom</label>
            <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[nom]" value="{{$user->nom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[prenom]" value="{{$user->prenom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Email</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[email]" value="{{$user->email}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
            <input type="text"  name="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" value ="{{$moyenne_avis->moyenne_avis}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
            <input type="text"  name="actif" class="form-control" value ="{{$moyenne_avis->actif}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </div>
            </div>




        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**controller1.php**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = $technicien->user;
    return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],
    ['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])->with('user',$user);
}
```

**controller2.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation

    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    $technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
    return redirect('technicien');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to change `method="update"` to `method="POST"` and in route `Route::patch` to `Route::post`

Comment: Why so many parameters in `route` method? It takes only 2 parameters, first is the name of the route, and 2nd is the array of parameters..

Comment: @HirenGohel same thing with POST

Comment: @Saiyan Prince i'm new to laravel could you please explain me more with code ?

Comment: @IT2704 Here is the entire series on Laravel and how it works.. GO through it.. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: @IT2704 : You are passing too many param and in your route you only take one param! I think you only need one param in your view which is technician ID and which will find the record in your controller query!

Comment: @HirenGohel thank you no more errors now the route works well but the problem is nothing changed in the database

Comment: @Jeune Guerrier Hi do you have an idea about this please

Comment: So there is some mistake in your code! Please post other question for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing too many param and in your route you only take one param!

I think you only need one param in your view which is technician ID and which will find the record in your controller query!

You can try follow code with removing unusable params from form:

```
<form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $moyenne_avis->id ) }}" method="POST">
```

And your route looks like:

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::post('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')->name('technicien.update');
```

Hope this helps you!